# pq: syntax error at or near "$1" Postgres + go

Tags: postgresql, go

What am i doing wrong here? Tried quoting new_name also , still shows error : pq: syntax error at or near "$1" Postgres + go

func ChangeDBname(new_name string) {

```
oldname := "intern"
quoted := pq.QuoteIdentifier(oldname)
_, e1 := db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO $1",quoted) , new_name)
if e1 != nil {
    fmt.Println("Eroor in change name")
    log.Fatal(e1.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Println("Table name changed to", new_name)
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot use parameter placeholders for identifiers. You can use them for values, but not names. You cannot for example use them for table names column names etc.

Answer (score 4):

Table name is not a value. So PostgreSQL parser is not expecting a placeholder in this DDL.

Check this:

```golang
db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("ALTER TABLE %s RENAME TO %s",pq.QuoteIdentifier(oldname), pq.QuoteIdentifier(new_name)))
```

Comment: but i want to inject the query , normal sting works